# Folder Shape flutter

Tags: flutter

[I want the folder shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCxMM.png)

I'm new in this framework and i want to make the shape fo the folder above, I do have this code so far, but it doenst look well

```
class FolderShapeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final a = 0;
  final b = 0.15;
  final c = 0.45;
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    return Path()
      ..moveTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height * 0.5)
      ..lineTo(0, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height)
      ..lineTo(size.width, size.height * 0.15)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, size.height * b)
      ..lineTo(size.width * c, 0)
      ..lineTo(size.width * a, 0)
      ..close();
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I'm expecting the folder shape,If anyone could help I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I have created a FolderPainter class for you;

```
class FolderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(86.351, 17.027);
    path_0.lineTo(35.525, 17.027);
    path_0.cubicTo(33.616, 17.027, 31.819, 16.124000000000002, 30.679, 14.592);
    path_0.lineTo(28.221999999999998, 11.290000000000001);
    path_0.cubicTo(27.409999999999997, 10.198, 26.128999999999998,
        9.555000000000001, 24.767999999999997, 9.555000000000001);
    path_0.lineTo(3.649, 9.555000000000001);
    path_0.cubicTo(1.634, 9.556, 0, 11.19, 0, 13.205);
    path_0.lineTo(0, 29.11);
    path_0.lineTo(0, 76.795);
    path_0.cubicTo(0, 78.81, 1.634, 80.444, 3.649, 80.444);
    path_0.lineTo(86.352, 80.444);
    path_0.cubicTo(88.367, 80.444, 90.001, 78.81, 90.001, 76.795);
    path_0.lineTo(90.001, 29.11);
    path_0.lineTo(90.001, 20.674999999999997);
    path_0.cubicTo(90, 18.661, 88.366, 17.027, 86.351, 17.027);
    path_0.close();

    Paint paint_0_stroke = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 2;
    paint_0_stroke.color = Color(0xff1b3e96);
    paint_0_stroke.strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0_stroke);

    Paint paint_0_fill = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_0_fill.color = Color(0xff1b3e96);
    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0_fill);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

and you can use this with this code;

```
Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: CustomPaint(painter: FolderPainter()),
  ),
)
```

And let's talk about how I created this perfect Folder Shape

Check out this web application; https://fluttershapemaker.com/#/

Here you can create a custom drawing. Moreover, you can import an SVG file and then export it as a custom painter.

[SVG to Custom Paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqrA8.png)

[Custom Paint Generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snHqR.png)

Good Luck